# Redirecting Open cart in to the xampp Dashboard Page

Tags: php, opencart-3

I have created the single store website in `Opencart`. I have edited database file and configured URL in database. I have created virtual host. However the new live site from server is not working properly. The site is being redirected to localhost/dashboard.

Comment: share your configured url

Comment: I think the APP_URL in env file is not your created virtual host name.